# Unable to exit from my OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I've just installed a Debian machine on a Google Cloud platform.
Now I have a Debian server and a Windows client.
I can ssh from my client to my server in a "vanilla" way.
After that I've installed an OpenVPN server on the Debian.
At this moment I can connect the 2 machines via OpenVPN.

But now start all my problems.
If I establish the VPN, I'm able to talk with between the 2 devices, but not with any others!

If I'm VPN connected my client stops to talk with the rest of the net.

under VPN I would like the following addressess
172.16.0.1 server
172.16.0.2 client

On server side

```
    # netstat -nr -f inet
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
    0.0.0.0         10.138.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens4
    10.138.0.1      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ens4
    172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
    
# cat  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1


    # iptables -S
    -P INPUT ACCEPT
    -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

what do I miss? if you need any other infos pleas let me know. Thank you

Here is my client OpenVPN configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xxx.hopto.org 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
xxx
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
xxx
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
xxx
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

And here is the server side

```
$ cat /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf
local 10.138.0.2
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
explicit-exit-notify
```

More information from the client, while connected:

```
>ping 1.1.1.1

Esecuzione di Ping 1.1.1.1 con 32 byte di dati:
Richiesta scaduta.
Richiesta scaduta.
Richiesta scaduta.
Richiesta scaduta.

Statistiche Ping per 1.1.1.1:
    Pacchetti: Trasmessi = 4, Ricevuti = 0,
    Persi = 4 (100% persi),

>tracert 1.1.1.1

Traccia instradamento verso 1.1.1.1 su un massimo di 30 punti di passaggio

  1   150 ms   149 ms   150 ms  172.16.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  3     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  4     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  5     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.

>nslookup unix.stackexchange.com 1.1.1.1
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  1.1.1.1

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
```

Update 2022-Mar-10

Here is the tracer log without the vpn

```
>tracert 1.1.1.1

Traccia instradamento verso one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]
su un massimo di 30 punti di passaggio:

  1     1 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     3 ms     1 ms     3 ms  2.112.209.88.static.monaco.mc [88.209.112.2]
  3     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  l5.pe01ftv.monaco-telecom.net [195.78.0.66]
  4     *        3 ms     3 ms  l1.pe01cst.monaco-telecom.net [195.78.0.65]
  5     6 ms     6 ms     8 ms  l500.pe01mrs.monaco-telecom.net [195.78.0.89]
  6     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  7     8 ms     7 ms     6 ms  be2065.ccr31.mrs02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.37.245]
  8    13 ms     *        *     149.6.154.130
  9    12 ms    12 ms    11 ms  one.one.one.one [1.1.1.1]

Traccia completata.
```

Update 18/mar/2022

I was googling arount the net to find a solution

I've found on a site a difference between my configuration and one on the site.

running the following command

```
$ sudo systemctl cat openvpn-iptables.service
```

I've noticed that I get the following resutls

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to 10.138.0.2
```

In the site in the **SNAT** part is indacted the pubblic address instead. Could it be the problem?

Comment: those ones are the IP that the client and the server are ment to have once the vpn is established. 
normally they have different addresses exposed on internet (one is the router IP and the second is the one that exposes google to internet.
Hope this answares your question

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that this is clear to everyone. Not everyone reads comments as they are intended only for seeking clarification

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

```
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

If you read the documentation for OpenVPN (`man openvpn` is a good starting point) you can find out what these options do:

> **`--redirect-gateway flags…`** Automatically execute routing commands to cause all outgoing IP traffic to be redirected over the VPN. This is a client-side option.

It then continues by explaining the two option flags:

> **`def1`** -- Use this flag to override the default gateway by using `0.0.0.0/1` and `128.0.0.0/1` rather than `0.0.0.0/0`. This  has  the benefit of overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
>
> **`bypass-dhcp`** -- Add a direct route to the DHCP server (if it is non-local)  which  bypasses  the tunnel […].

The `redirect-gateway` option is sent by the server to the client upon connection. It tells the client to send *all traffic* via the VPN. Not just data for the target network, but everything.

It seems to me that you do not want this option, but that only traffic for the target network should be routed via the VPN.

Comment: I have tried to remove the string in the server conf, and restarted the service.
After that I've relogged with the client, but the problem persist... any other idea? :'-(

Comment: BTW thank you @roaima anyway for your support :-)

Comment: @SKAL, "_the problem persist_" - when your client is connected, can it `ping 1.1.1.1`? If you `traceroute 1.1.1.1` (or `tracert 1.1.1.1` on Windows) does the printed route travel via the server or direct? It should be direct. While connected can you `nslookup unix.stackexchange.com 1.1.1.1` and get an answer, or does it time out?

Comment: nothing seem to work :-(

Comment: @SKAL please disconnect the VPN client and again try `tracert 1.1.1.1`. I'm particularly interested in the first few lines of the result

Comment: I've added you the tracert without the vpn

Comment: Some more infos added in the first post about iptables.